# problems with npm install and link

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running into a lot of friction while creating a command line app with node and npm.  I have previously done simple projects but now messing with commands like `npm link` seems to have gotten me into trouble.

For example, now when trying to install a package:

```
alexanderbollbachs-MacBook-Pro:pmcli alexanderbollbach$ npm install cli-table --save
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alexanderbollbach/.npm/_logs/2017-07-11T22_39_32_076Z-debug.log
```

[and the log file..](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/0b34c1ff017977debddb6e68dc641f44)

Running `npm link`:

```
Unhandled rejection RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded0.0~preinstall: no script for preinstall, c
    at exports.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/node.js:33:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/node.js:36:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at exports.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/node.js:33:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/node.js:36:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at exports.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/node.js:33:25)
    at normalizeTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:377:5)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at normalizeTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:379:19)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at normalizeTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:379:19)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at normalizeTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:379:19)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at normalizeTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:379:19)

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alexanderbollbach/.npm/_logs/2017-07-11T22_42_51_880Z-debug.log
```

[and this log file](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/a1836478e3b54e2070958f25fb857026)

I'd appreciate any insight as to what the problem may be.  I've read that installing with `Homebrew` can led to issues.  Perhaps the node<->npm configuration is mismatched.  I did mess around in the `~/.npm-packages/bin` and `.../lib/node-mules/` directories so perhaps I accidentally deleted some necessary files (though those should be regenerated on subsequent invocations of `link`).  I'm also not fully sure about what link does exactly so any clarification on this process would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Only for prevent, install lates npm, 'npm i -g npm'

Comment: what do you mean "only for prevent"?

Comment: Track and read through this issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9224 to see if you can find a solution, and if not, you can post your problem there.

Comment: @AlexBollbach mmm to exclude a possible error related to old version of npm :)